# How to get Web3js to work inside a VueJS component?

Tags: node.js, vuejs2, vue-component, parity, web3js

I want to use web3 with node and vuejs to connect to an Ethereum Parity node.

- I am using vue-cli with webpack.
- Parity is running on localhost.
- When I visit `http://localhost:8545` I see which tells me Parity is listening.

[image]

I created the following Vue component:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <h2>{{ accounts() }}</h2>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Web3 from 'web3'

  export default {
    name: 'hello',
    http: {
      root: '/root',
      headers: {
        AccessControlAllowOrigin: 'true'
      }
    },
    data () {
      return {
        title: 'web3.js App'
      }
    },
    methods: {
      accounts: function () {
        const ethereumUri = 'http://localhost:8545'   // 8540, 8545, 8180

        let web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(ethereumUri))

        if (!web3.isConnected()) {
          return 'Unable to connect to ethereum node at ' + ethereumUri
        } else {
          let accounts = web3.eth.accounts
          return accounts
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

When I run `npm run dev` I get this:

[image]

On the console I see this:

[image]

I attempted to add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header using this configuration code, but it did not fix it. The console error seems to indicate that the Parity node needs to set this header option.

```
    http: {
      root: '/root',
      headers: {
        AccessControlAllowOrigin: 'true'
      }
    },
```

Comment: You should allow cross-domain requests on your back-end.

Comment: I thought thats what my http: { headers: {} } settings are supposed to do.

Comment: Parity docs say you can do this: 
`[rpc]
cors = "*"
hosts = ["*"].`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to create a Parity config file named `config.toml`.

**File Location:**

- Windows: %UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Parity\Ethereum\config.toml
- Linux: ~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/config.toml
- macOS: $HOME/Library/Application Support/io.parity.ethereum/config.toml

**File Contents:**

```
[parity]
#  Test Network 
chain = "ropsten"

[rpc]
# Allows Cross-Origin Requests from domain '*'. 
cors = "*"
# Allow connections only using specified addresses. 
hosts = ["", "http://localhost:8080"]
```

**Reference:**

- Parity configuration file [documentation](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Configuring-Parity).
- Parity config file [generator](https://paritytech.github.io/parity-config-generator/).
- Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Thank you wostex for the comment.